# Stop emberjs to send request to server for loaded record

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I am having a `customer` model and a `product` model

**customer model**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.Model.extend({
    type: DS.attr('string'),
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    product: DS.hasMany('product')
});
```

**product model**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.Model.extend({
    type: DS.attr('string'),
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    customer: DS.belongsTo('customer')
});
```

I load all the customer in `model()` hook of route.js as below

```
model() {
    customers: this.store.findAll('customer'),
}
```

so as of now I have all the records of customer.

then using `findRecord` method I load perticular product as

```
this.store.findRecord('product', productId);
```

I call this on `click` of a `button` say **Find Products**, this is written in **controller.js**

now when I write in template as

```
{{product.customer.name}}
```

it send a get request to load the customer which is already loaded. I want to stop that request how I can do this ?

As per my knowledge

> When we already have the record, store.findRecord will resolve immediately with cached data, but will send a request in the background to update the record and once the record is updated your template will show the new changes.

I want to stop that request.

Comment: Yes `findRecord` returns a promise which resolves immediately if the record is found in the store. Are you sure your `model` promise is resolved when `findRecord` is called ? Where and when do you call this `this.store.findRecord('product', productId);` ?

Comment: Unrelated. Product: DS.belongsTo('customer') Why would a product belong to a customer?

Comment: Also there's no signs of you quering a product in model hook. Where do you do that?

Comment: @dynamic_cast I call it on a button click. I want to load the product of specific customer.

Comment: @kristjanreinhold a customer has many products, so product belongsTo customer. I am not loading product in model hook. I do it on click action of a button

Comment: Product does not belong to a user. If you want such relation you would have to have UserProducts table (FK product FK user) e.g (p: 1, u :1) (p: 1,u: 2)

Comment: @kristjanreinhold relation is fine and it is working well. problem is, it is sending request when customer is already loaded it should fetch from cache only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112799/discussion-between-murli2308-and-kristjan-reinhold).

Comment: Ok so what if 2 customers want to buy the same product, how is your schema going to handle this easy case ? Why are you DS.belongs/hasMany not defined as async? It's a default behaviour since ember-data 2.

Comment: If you know your data is in the store and you don't want to hit the server, why don't you use peekRecord instead of findRecord. https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/models/finding-records/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.

> If we return false from **shouldBackgroundReloadAll** and **shouldBackgroundReloadRecord**, then also ember will send background request if the model we are looking for is in belongsTo relationship.

In template I am calling customer name

```
{{product.customer.name}}
```

It is sending ajax request as it has belongsTo relationship.

I overriding the method `findBelongsTo` in the **adapters/application.js**. I am checking whether record is loaded or not if loaded then do not send request

```
findBelongsTo: function(store, snapshot, url, relationship) {
    var record = store.peekRecord(relationship.type, url);
    if(record){
      return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          // on success
          var r = Ember.copy(record._internalModel._data, true);
          r._id = record.id;
          var d ={ meta: {} };
          d[Ember.String.pluralize(relationship.type)] = [r];
          resolve(d);
          // on failure
          reject(null);
         });
    } else{
          url = this.buildURL(relationship.type, url, snapshot, 'findRecord');
          return this.ajax(url, 'GET');
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks pretty hacky and break-prone if you update ember or ember-data, have you tried something simpler like `if (record) { return Ember.RSVP.resolve(record); } else { return this._super(...arguments); }`?

Comment: @Terseus `record` is a `Class` it needs a promise which will resolve to `JSON` format

Answer (score 5):

You problem is probably that ember-data does not know that the requested customer is already in the store. In your own answer you use the url to peek the customer, so I assume your `id` is your url, and thats probably your problem.

There is to mention that ember-data *should* work as you expect, so you are doing something wrong. Since you haven't shown your adapter, serializer and response I can not tell you exactly what's wrong, but I can show you where to look to it.

Also to mention is that you have an attribute `type`. This is probably not what you want, because the `type` is, as the `id`, an ember internal and you should *not* declare it yourself.

There seems also to be an syntax error in your `model` hook, because you use the `:` like in a object definition:

```
model() {
  customers: this.store.findAll('customer'),
}
```

You have to understand that `model(){}` is a function, and identical to `model: function() {}`!

What you *should* do is to load all the customers with `findAll`, but its essential to wait for the promise to be resolved until you ask for the customer on the product. So you should do something like this:

```
model() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
        customers: this.store.findAll('customer'),
        product: this.store.find('product', 1),
    }).then(h => h.product);
}
```

---

I have built a little [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/d51c3288c59c260f77a2df2b461127e6?openFiles=templates.index.hbs%2C) with your situation, and as you see there is no request made for the customer, but also the customer is not shown. This is because of how I mock the server response in the adapter:

```
export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
  findRecord (store, type, id, snapshot)  {
    console.log('find product ', id);
    return Ember.RSVP.resolve({
      data: {
        id: '2',
        type: 'product',
        attributes: { name: 'product-one'},
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Because the `customer` relationship is not declared ember-data assumes it has none. Lets [fix this](https://ember-twiddle.com/f21ea13e18021e87e66b8460a5fb4987?openFiles=adapters.product.js%2C) by including the customer in the product like this:

```
return Ember.RSVP.resolve({
  data: {
    id: '2',
    type: 'product',
    attributes: { name: 'product-one'},
    relationships: {
      customer: {
        links: {
          related: '/customers/1'
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Now I have exact the same situation as you have! Ember ties to fetch the customer it already has. Is is because ember-data does not know that it has the customer, because it only knows his url, not his id. This is also the reason why the background reload hooks don't work for you, because its not a reload for ember-data, its an initial load!

Its pretty easy to fix this by just [giving ember-data the information](https://ember-twiddle.com/cf359599e781a6d030eca0752de2b0ba?openFiles=adapters.product.js%2C):

```
customer: {
    data: { type: 'customer', id: '1' },
    links: {
        related: '/customers/1'
    }
}
```

And woha, everything works! Now you could even remove the related link because ember-data could just build it by its own.

So in conclusion the right place to fix this is either to adjust the server response itself, or use the serializer to fix it so ember-data can know if it already has the record.

Comment: This is not solving my issue. My problem is, Ember is calling the data even if data is present in store. `shouldBackgroundReloadAll` and `shouldBackgroundReloadRecord` is not working for the items which I declare as in relationship.

Comment: This *is* you problem! `shouldBackgroundReloadAll` and `shouldBackgroundReloadRecord` are *not* for relationship requests but for `find` and `findAll` requests by design. You problem is that ember-data has the data, but *does not know that*. Have checked out the twiddles? If you would provide more information, your adapter, serializer and response we could probably help you better but this *is* your problem!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this.store.peekRecord('product', productId) instead of findRecord. Peek will return results without doing a network request. It will completely rely on what is already in store.

Comment: It will indeed, but it should be noted that it would remove the chance to actually make a request if the record is not present in store. In this case it's fine since all records are supposed to have been retrieved in the model hook anyway.

Comment: `peekRecord` is not the solution it will never send request to server. I want a method which will send request to server it data is not present in cache

Comment: @murli2308 so why don't you do a peekRecord and if nothing is found do the findRecord?

Comment: @Vlad I am not calling the findRecord. when model is in belongsTo relationship the XHR requests fires by itself even if the record is in store..

Answer (score 2):

`DS.Adapter` classes have methods for this specific need (and therefore all other adapters):

- [shouldBackgroundReloadAll](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Adapter.html#method_shouldBackgroundReloadAll) for background reload in `store.findAll` calls.
- [shouldBackgroundReloadRecord](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Adapter.html#method_shouldBackgroundReloadRecord) for background reload in `store.findRecord` calls.
- [shouldReloadAll](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Adapter.html#method_shouldReloadAll) for **blocking** reload in `store.findAll` calls.
- [shouldReloadRecord](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Adapter.html#method_shouldReloadRecord) for **blocking** reload in `store.findRecord` calls.

If any of these methods returns `false`, the store will not reload the record/s/ from the backend.

However I would recommend to have some care if you override them, otherwise I suspect some things may stop working as expected, read the documentation about these methods and do some research about its implications.

Comment: I tried `shouldBackgroundReloadAll() {return false;},shouldBackgroundReloadRecord() {return false;}` but it is still sending and request in background and if I return false in next two methods it will never send request to server